# How to tell if Airplane Mode is on?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-configuration, airplane-mode

Action Center tells me that Airplane Mode is on:
[image]

Whereas, The WiFi menu tells me that it is not:

[image]

So, is it On or Off?
**EDIT:** It isn't that simple... most devices will let you turn WiFi on even if Airplane mode is on. [Emirates offers WiFi on its planes :D ]

Both WiFi and Airplane Mode on:
[image: WifiAir]

Comment: @fixer1234 What? I didn't get it... :/

Comment: I should pay more attention when writing wise-ass comments.  Should have said a foolproof way to tell that airplane more is **off** is if they confiscate your device and handcuff you to the seat on the airplane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WiFi symbol is not showing as an aeroplane, so it isn't on.

Why that is happening I'm not sure, but I would try rebooting and seeing if it persisted. Otherwise, just a strange graphical bug, but nothing to worry about.

This is how it looks when correctly activated:

[image]

Comment: WiFi and Airplane mode can be on at the same time...

Comment: Press the WiFi button while Airplane mode is on and see...

Comment: @RahulBasu Indeed, but the icon stays as an Airplane icon. Will change my answer.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think it's a graphical bug.